# Ubuntu Desktop corporate warning splash page

Tags: login, .desktop

Good Afternoon

The Windows servers in my office have a corporate warning splash page whenever a user logs on to the system.  The user would then have to click "ok" to acknowledge the warning that this is a company computer and there are legal ramifications for the misuse of the computer and so on......  I was wondering if there is a similar function for the Ubuntu desktop.  The window with the warning would pop up after log on and then the user would have to click ok to acknowledge the warning and close the window.

Thank you in advance.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a zenity warning, something like this:

zenity --warning --title="corporate guidelines" --text="put your rules here"

Will output this:

[image]

I don't remember if zenity is installed by default, but it's just:

```
sudo apt-get install zenity
```

I'm sure you can improve this to make a little script where the user is loged in, and close the session if the user doesn't accept the guidelines. For that, you can use gnome-session-properties to call zenity directly, or to call an script that contains the warning.

Comment: The main problem is where to put it... you can stick it in `~/.xprofile`, but then the user can delete it. I imagine that the answer will be dependent on the login manager (gdm, lightdm, kdm...)

Comment: You can also put it in the default applications startup, systemwide, so it will work for all the users and they won't be able to override it.

Comment: Yep --- where? In gnome, startup applications, I have no option to set system-wide ones... is there some special directory where to put them, DM independent?